# A question on continuity of functions

Tags: calculus, continuity

> $f(x) = \text{sgn}(\cos 2x - 2 \sin x + 3)$, where sgn(.) is the signum function. Then $f(x)$
>   A) is continuous over its domain.
>   B) has a missing point discontinuity.
>   C) has an isolated point discontinuity.
>   D) irremovable discontinuity.

The quadratic equation can be written as:

$-2\sin^2 x - 2\sin x + 4$

Making perfect square,

$-2\Big(\sin x+\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2+\frac{9}{2}$

Now, this would always be positive. Its range lying between $\Big(0,\frac{9}{2}\Big)$. Therefore, its signum would always be $1$. So, the answer according to me should be A). But the answer is B), D).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When $x = \pi/2$, you have that $\cos(2x)−2\sin(x)+3$ is equal to zero so that signum is not always $1$. This induces the discontinuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the expression
$$-2\Big(\sin x+\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2+\frac{9}{2}$$
This is not always positive, since the maximum value of $\sin(x)$ is $1$, and evaluated at $\sin(x)=1$, this is equal to
$$-2\Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^2+\frac{9}{2}=0$$
and $\text{sgn}(0)=0$. Thus, your original function is discontinuous at
$$x=\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}$$
for $n\in\mathbb Z^+$.